# function firing after return

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function submitQuestionFunction(){
var question = document.getElementById("questionSearchInput").value;
var email = document.getElementById("emailTextInput").value;
if(question == null){
    alert("you must ask a question");
    return false;
}
if(question == ""){
    alert("you must ask a question");
    return false;
}
if(email == null){
    alert("you must Fill in your email");
    return false;
}
if(email == ""){
    alert("you must Fill in your email");
    return false;
}
var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos< 1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
}
$.post("askQuestion.php", {"question":question, "email":email}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    location.href = "http://www.example.com/questionAsked.html";
});
}
```

ok the function is pretty straightforward. It gets fired on an onclick event on a button in the html. The problem is that even if you don't fill out the questionSearchInput field or the emailTextInput feild. the function alerts but the browser refreshes. instead of returning false.

It's worth noting that I was getting an error before this about submitQuestion() not being a function. So I changed it to submitquestionFunction(). I'm not sure that that was the original problem. For some reason the browser doesn't like my function. It's declared in the 
of the page. The onclick in the body. I honestly don't know whats wrong.

Also without the field tests the function will not make the post request. The browser just refreshes.

Comment: Show your HTML? Is your button inside a form element and How are you using the above function?

Comment: Are you using `onclick="submitQuestionFunction()"` or `onclick="return submitQuestionFunction()"`?

Comment: you did not show any html in your previous question, you are not showing any html here. Apparently, the form is submitted as a result of the button click, so the solution may be to change button type from submit to button.

Comment: i did have the button inside of a form, changing that removed the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would change a few things.

I would use if/else if/else to properly structure your conditions. Also combine the conditions for checking values as null or blank string to cut down code. Lastly instead of using the indexof lastindex of to check for valid email use regex to check the string.

The regex in the jsfiddle will not allow xx@..xy which is an invalid address but your code currently will.

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/4nu6utLc/

```
function submitQuestionFunction() {

    var question = $("#questionSearchInput").val();
    var email = $("#emailTextInput").val();
    var emailRegEx = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

    if (question == null || question == "") {
        alert("you must ask a question");
        return false;
    } else if (email == null || email == "") {
        alert("you must Fill in your email");
        return false;
    } else if (emailRegEx.test(email) == false) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    } else {

        //$.post("askQuestion.php", {"question":question, "email":email}, function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        //location.href = "http://www.example.com/questionAsked.html";
        //});
        alert("everything is valid POST!");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer but the regex isn't quite right.  `xx+abc@jhhujh.xy` is valid but the regex flags the "plus" as wrong

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated fiddle and add test here. http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/1zrk0fLd/

Comment: the "plus" is the first thing I check whenever I look at email validation.  It drives me nuts when I can't use an addres like: `david+someRetailerThatWillProbablySpamMe@gmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling your function from a submit button inside a form you may want to add/change your function to start with:

```
function submitQuestionFunction(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/forloop/EdJQE/

Comment: i did have the button inside of a form, changing that removed the problem, thanks.